ViewController не занимает все доступное пространство
Удалил Storyboard, настроил SceneDelegate:
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

И при простом запуске ViewController
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
    }
}

Получаю максимально странный результат


констрейнты поставить по 0 0 0 0 (тогда будет на весь экран)

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Чтобы исправить проблему с размером View, попробуйте настроить размер окна в SceneDelegate. Для этого добавьте следующие строки после создания окна:
window?.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
window?.safeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
Это должно установить размер окна равным размеру экрана устройства и убрать безопасные отступы (safe area), которые могут влиять на отображение контента.
